# How to make wordpress Mobile website like m.facebook.com (Mobile Version)?

Tags: wordpress, mobile

I want to develop a mobile website and I'm highly impressed with the (m.facebook.com). Can anyone give me any idea how can I be able to make that type of mobile website? Which plugins/hacks are highly required by that type of development for a mobile website?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This question is outside the scope of Stack Overflow. See: [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) You are expected to have researched your issue and made attempts to solve it before posting, and questions should include a summary of what you have tried so far and the relevant code in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and come back when you have a specific coding question to ask.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that you're using mobile and reactive interchangeably, though I could very well be wrong.  Anyway:

tldr: A good mobile theme is 80-100% of the solution.

**A little history and vocabulary:**

In the earlier days of mobile, when it was a new thing, sites would detect mobile users and send them a completely different site.  So people supported a mobile site, and the regular site.

Reactive design is technically something different.  Several technologies, the leading one being Twitter bootstrap, let developers build single websites whose elements changed size / shape / visibility based on the size of screen through which they were being viewed.

So mobile and reactive are technically different, though people use them interchangeable.

I would guess that FB has the resources to support a completely separate mobile site.  For most other people and organizations, it makes a lot more sense to build one good reactive site.

So think about resources -- cost of development and cost of maintenance --  before creating a whole separate site.

**So**

I would recommend a good reactive site.  This is already pretty mature technology.  I would expect most of your time should be spent trying different reactive themes, tweaking them, and finding the best match.

To refine things, you'd probably want some analytics software running through which you can compare differences in user behavior between desktop and mobile users.

If you install any WP plugins that effect your site's appearance, you'll also want to test those.  Sometimes a theme can be very mobile friendly, but plug-ins mess things up.

I see there are some mobile specific WP plugins.  Jetpack also has some mobile-specific functionality.  I'm not aware of their specifics.  In my experience, the theme is 80-100% of the solution to a good reactive site.